# Shiny/R interactive plot not displayed, no error shown

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to create a report using shiny R, including an intro page and a main page with an interactive graph. All other stuff works fine but the graph won't display and there's no error in R studio.

My code in ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
source("app_server.R")

first_page <- tabPanel(
  "Introduction",
  titlePanel("CO2 Emissions around the World"),
  p("intro text)
)

second_page <- tabPanel(
  "Interactive Chart",
  titlePanel("CO2 Emissions Per capita of All Countries throughout History"),
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(
        inputId = "country_choice",
        label = "Choose a Country",
        choices = unique(climate_data$country)
      ),
        
     sliderInput(
          inputId = "year_choice",
          label = "Year",
          min = 1950,
          max = 2021,
          value = c(1950, 2021),
          sep = ""
      ) 
    ),
 
      mainPanel(
         plotlyOutput("plot"),
         p("text caption")
      )
  )
)


ui <- navbarPage(
  "Climate change",
  first_page,
  second_page
)
```

Here's my server.R:

```
library("shiny")
library("tidyverse")
library("ggplot2")
library("plotly")

climate_data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/co2-data/master/owid-co2-data.csv")

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  new_data <- reactive ({
    new_df <- climate_data %>%
              filter(country == input$country_choice) %>%
              filter(year >= input$year_choice[1]) %>%
              filter(year <= input$year_choice[2]) 
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
  p <- ggplot(data = new_df, aes (x = year, y = co2_per_capita)) + 
    geom_line()
  p <- ggplotly(p)
  p
  })
}
```

I thought the problem might be the code of the graph in server.R, but I tried everything and it still shows nothing but the text and title.

Comment: Try with `ggplot(data = new_data(), aes(...))`. `new_df` is a local variable defined inside the `reactive` `new_data` and hence not available outside of the`new_data`.

Comment: I tried new_data(), still no plot displayed.

Comment: Remove `new_df <- ` your reactive is defining a local variable but not returning anything. And use 'new_data()` in @stefan comment

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment the reactive is not returning any value, change server to this

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  new_data <- reactive ({
    climate_data %>%
      filter(country == input$country_choice) %>%
      filter(year >= input$year_choice[1]) %>%
      filter(year <= input$year_choice[2]) 
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(data = new_data(), aes (x = year, y = co2_per_capita)) + 
      geom_line()
    p <- ggplotly(p)
    p
  })
}
```